# Local variable referenced before assignment, except its never used outside of the function

Tags: python-3.x, class

I created the following classes for a game of Wheel of Fortune. When I run the program, I get 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sorted_list' referenced before assignment'. However, when I run the program, I sometimes get this error and sometimes a correct response, so I think this has something to do with the random number portion of the code as well.

Here is the code, the bottom 3 lines are just there for testing purposes:

```
import random

VOWEL_COST = 250
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
VOWELS = 'AEIOU'

class WOFPlayer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.prizeMoney = 0
        self.prizes = []
    
    def addMoney(self, amt):
        self.prizeMoney += amt
    
    def goBankrupt(self):
        self.prizeMoney = 0
    
    def addPrize(self, prize):
        self.prizes.append(prize)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} (${})'.format(self.name, self.prizeMoney)


class WOFHumanPlayer(WOFPlayer):
    def getMove(self, category, obscuredPhrase, guessed):
        return input("""{} has ${}

Category: {}
Phrase:  {}
Guessed: {}

Guess a letter, phrase, or type 'exit' or 'pass':)""". format(self.name, self.prizeMoney, category, obscured_phrase, guessed))

class WOFComputerPlayer(WOFPlayer):

    def __init__(self, name, difficulty):
        WOFPlayer.__init__(self, name)
        self.difficulty = difficulty
    SORTED_FREQUENCIES = 'ZQXJKVBPYGFWMUCLDRHSNIOATE'
    def smartCoinFlip(self):
        flip = random.randint(1, 10)
        if flip > self.difficulty:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    
    def getPossibleLetters(self, guessed):
        possible_letters = []
        for x in LETTERS:
            if x in VOWELS and self.prizeMoney < VOWEL_COST:
                continue
            if x in guessed:
                continue
            possible_letters.append(x)
            return possible_letters

    
    def getMove(self, category, obscuredPhrase, guessed):
        possible_letters = self.getPossibleLetters(guessed)
        if possible_letters == []:
            return 'pass'
        coinflip = self.smartCoinFlip()
        if coinflip == True:
            sorted_list = sorted(possible_letters, reverse = True, key = lambda x: WOFComputerPlayer.SORTED_FREQUENCIES.find(x))
            return sorted_list[0]
        else:
            return sorted_list[

random.randrange(len(sorted_list))]

x = WOFComputerPlayer('boy', 5)
y = x.getMove('matter', 'co______', 'co')
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the initialization of the `sorted_list` out of the `if/else` block. If `coinflip` is False, the control moves to `else` block which doesn't has the context of the `sorted_list`.

Bonus: Don't use `else` block if the only statement is `return`

```
def getMove(self, category, obscuredPhrase, guessed):
        possible_letters = self.getPossibleLetters(guessed)
        if possible_letters == []:
            return 'pass'
        coinflip = self.smartCoinFlip()
        sorted_list = sorted(possible_letters, reverse = True, key = lambda x: WOFComputerPlayer.SORTED_FREQUENCIES.find(x))
        if coinflip == True:
            return sorted_list[0]
        return sorted_list[random.randrange(len(sorted_list))]
```